# how to generate proxy class for sharepoint at runtime

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint site (given below) which I am able to add as a service reference and code for creating lists and editing lists.

https://sharepoint.eastasia.minesoft.com/sites/UnityTest/StationTest/_vti_bin/lists.asmx

The problem with my code is its always hard coded to above test sharepoint site.If I want to resuse the code I feel I should some how take the url of sharepoint at runtime and generate the proxy class..

My code looks like below:

```
        ListsSoapClient client = new ListsSoapClient();            
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        client.Open();
```

Comment: I didn't get why you can't reuse the code. If you need to point to another SP, just change the URL in the properties of your app (since the list.asmx has the same contract).

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make your code use REST endpoints, you can change the URL at runtime and then deserialize the return values:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("mysharpeointurl/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('libraryname')/Items?$select=ID,Title");
        var response = client.GetAsync(uri);
        string text = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Returned.RootObject));
        Returned.RootObject rootObject = null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text))) {
            var documentdata = (Returned.RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            rootObject = documentdata;
        }

        return rootObject;
```

That way, you just change the URI at runtime but if both sites return the same objects with properties available on the data contract (Returned.RootObject), you'll be able to get back the data.  And by doing the $select statement on the REST, you only get back what you want and can avoid sending extra data over the network.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following.

```
client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(newUrl);
```

Comment: Re: downvote: Setting the endpoint address didn't work? Let me know how it failed and I can look into it a little more.